# Tridion Core Service 2013

Tags: 2013, core-service

We are running the same program based in the core service. When changing the endpoint, we've got an error in our production environment:

> Error to read Components: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Negotitate'. The authentication header received
>   from the serves was Negotiate,NTML

We are using the basicHttp binding and initializing the credentials in the code:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient cs = new Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceClient("basicHttp_2013");
cs.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username"; 
cs.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

The conf is:

```
<endpoint name="basicHttp_2013" address="http://our_ip/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ICoreService" />
```

Comment: as you mentioned "When changing the endpoint", Which endpoint you were using before?

Comment: you can try `cs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");`

Comment: The change in the endpoint between both environments was IP, code is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following step, the first one recently resolve my similar issue.

- Disable/update Loopback in registry:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861
- NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
                         CoreServiceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;